# How to find files without a specific attribute?

Tags: file, winapi, search, attributes, filesystems

I need to find files that do NOT have an Offline attribute (FILE_ATTRIBUTE_OFFLINE) within a large subtree. I looked at what Directory.EnumerateFileSystemEntries() .NET method provides and also at FindFirstFile/FindFirstFileEx() Win32 API but none of them provide a method for searching for specific attribute or its absence. Am I missing something?

What would be the fastest way to find files without a specific attribute? Do I need to traverse the tree and check every file for attribute presence?

Comment: I would be nice but Windows file systems are generally not like SQL databases :-) There was a plan once https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WinFS

Comment: *Do I need to traverse the tree and check every file for attribute presence?* - yes